# Clear the Input type file Value if the Modal has been Closed and Save All changes button should be disabled

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-4

How are you ? I'm working on simple project and I want to do a simple trick in my app.
I want to **Clear the Input type file Value if the Modal has been Closed**
mean if the user decided to Cancel the upload and close the modal I want to reset the input value to be empty and **Save All changes Button** should be disabled if the value is empty ....

**HTML CODE :**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modal_a" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modal_aLabel" aria-hidden="true"data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-scrollable" role="document">
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-body">
   <div class="uploadavatar">
        <input type="file" 
               class="custom-file-input" 
               id="ID12" 
               name="avatar"
               value=""
               hidden />
        <label role="button" class="btn" for="ID12">
            Upload Now
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="button1" disabled>Save All changes</button>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

**JS CODE :**

```
$(document).on('shown.bs.modal', '#modal_a', function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('show')) {
        $('#ID12').on('change', function() {
            if ($(this).val() == '') {
                $('#button1').prop('disabled', true);
            } else {
                $('#button1').prop('disabled', false);
            }
            $(this).attr('value', $(this).val());
        });
    }
});
$(document).on('hide.bs.modal', '#modal_a', function(e) {
    if ($('#ID12').val() != '') {
        const CancelUpdateConfirmation = confirm('Are you sure!  you want to Close the modal and Cancel your Upload? ');
        if (!CancelUpdateConfirmation) {
            e.preventDefault();
        } else {

        }
    }
});
```

Comment: What is the issue are facing?

Comment: I want to clear the input value if the user choose to close the modal end cancel the file upload means when he opened the modal the value should be empty and buttons should be disabled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $('#exampleModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
    $('#ID12').val('')
    $('#button1').prop('disabled', true);
  })
  $('#exampleModal').on('hide.bs.modal', function (e) {
      if ($('#ID12').val() != '') {
        const CancelUpdateConfirmation = confirm('Are you sure!  you want to Close the modal and Cancel your Upload? ');
        if (!CancelUpdateConfirmation) {
            e.preventDefault();
        } else {

        }
    }
  })
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <input type="file" 
         id="ID12" 
         name="avatar"
         value=""
         />
         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="button1">Save All changes</button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it works but when i opened the modal again the submit button should be disabled means when you cancel the upload it should be returned to disabled button

Comment: thank you my friend so mush it works well thank you